# Usb Debugging connected state

Tags: android, usb-debugging

Is there any way to findout the device connected to PC with USB debugging? Inside the app. not from ADB

[image]

Clarification:

- It's not about checking USB Debugging on [Assume it's always on]
- Not Listening to this event

I tried with following hack:

```
private boolean isConnected() {
    IntentFilter ifilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED);
    Intent batteryStatus = this.registerReceiver(null, ifilter);
    int status = batteryStatus.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_STATUS, -1);
    return status == BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_CHARGING;
}
```

Not working with all devices. (esp. tablets)